# Arrays, movement, and error 1010

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a very simple vertical bullet projectile system (bullets move at a consistant pace, bullets can have a hitTestObject applied, etc), but I'm having difficulties putting something together.

At-the-moment my code is:

```
// define timer
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(15);
// define array [list]
var list:Array = new Array();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.start();

function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void
{

    var Create:Bullet = new Bullet();
    addChild(Create);
    // Starting position
    Create.x = 150;
    Create.y = 150;
    // Push into list
    list.push(Create);
}

for (var i:int; i <= 10; i++){
    list[i].x + 10;
    i++;
    if (i > 10){
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is I've been having all kinds of issues using for/while/etc when it comes to trying to reference list[i].x and having all the objects move at a consistant pace, including #1010 errors.

If anyone knows a better way to do what I'm looking for, or the fix to my current code, it would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are moving your list of bullets, you need to properly index the list. The reason you are getting #1010 'undefined' errors is because list[i] is not always defined. You should also remove any bullets that have moved off the screen. I used 300 pixels as an arbitrary cut-off point. you should call moveBullets() on a timer, possible on your 15ms timer above.

try this:

```
function moveBullets():void{
  var target:Bullet;
  for(var i:int=0;i<list.length;i++){
    target = Bullet(list[i]);
    target.x +=10;
    if(target.x > 300){
      removeChild(target);
      list.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed for everything to work properly! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

You running the `for` loop before there is any buttets added to the stage.

the function for `for` loop should be something like this:

```
// define timer
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(15);
// define array [list]
var list:Array = new Array();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.start();

function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void
{

    var Create:Bullet = new Bullet();
    addChild(Create);
    // Starting position
    Create.x = 150;
    Create.y = 150;
    // Push into list
    list.push(Create);
}

// the for loop functionality:
addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame );

function handleEnterFrame ( e : Event )
{
//    for (var i:int; i <= 10; i++) -> why 10?

    var length_i:uint = list.length;
    var bulletMC:Bullet;
    for (var i:uint; i <= length_i; i++)
    {
        bulletMC = list[i];
        // list[i].x + 10; -> almost :)
        bulletMC.x += 10;

        // i++; -> you do need to do this the for loop automaticaly increases the i variable.

        // then you need to check if you still need the bullet ( is it of of the stage )
        if ( bulletMC.x > stage.stageWidth ) // here can be some other parameter
        {
            list.splice(i,1)
            list.removeChild ( bulletMC );
            i--; // since we removed one bullet from the array
            length_i = list.length // updating the lenght of the array
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the second for loop (the one that is responsible for moving the bullets) runs before even a single bullet is created. This is why you get a null pointer exception: The Flash Player is trying to move objects that do not exist (yet).  You must always make sure objects exist, before you call them.

Also, a for loop like this will merely iterate over the bullets in the list, but it will not take in account that motion occurs *over time*.  You can, of course, put that for loop in another for loop, etc.etc., to make it run over and over again - but all this will do is freeze your computer, because you don't allow the screen to refresh in between movements.

In short: **The motion loop needs to be in a function you call periodically.**

Also, iterating over arrays is tedious using a counter variable - you can use `for... in` and just forget about lengths and such.

```
var createTimer : Timer = new Timer ( 15 );

var maxBullets : uint = 10;
var moveSpeed : uint = 10;

var list : Array = [];

createTimer.addEventListener ( TimerEvent.TIMER, onCreationTimer );
createTimer.start ();

addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame ); // <= this will call the 
                                                      //    motion loop each 
                                                      //    time the screen 
                                                      //    refreshes.

function onEnterFrame ( event : Event ) : void
{
    for each ( var bullet : Bullet in list) // <= move bullets and remove if off-screen
        if ((bullet.x += moveSpeed) > stage.stageWidth)
            removeChild ( list.splice ( list.indexOf ( bullet ), 1 )[0] );
}

function onCreationTimer ( e : TimerEvent ) : void
{
    if (list.length >= maxBullets) return;

    var bullet : Bullet = new Bullet ();
    list.push ( addChild ( bullet ) );
    bullet.x = bullet.y = 150;
}
```